# How to update Object in mongo via PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, nosql

I've asked to update an Object in mongo, (I am kinda new in NoSQL) so.. much I know is from guides and so, currently I am using this [Codeigniter MongoDB library](https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/codeigniter-mongodb-library) which simplifies the task.

So, this is the object I have stored in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5cfdc59844d81560d407a2e3"),
    "equipo": "2bdca4c0-854d-4f73-bca8-cfb78a31f928",
    "jugadores": {
        "5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc": {
            "tipo": "i",
            "estado": false,
            "nombre": "name",
            "apellido_st": "last_name",
            "apellido_nd": "second_last_name",
            "email": "email@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the 'query' I am using to update it.

```php
$this->mongo->where(array
(
    "equipo" => "2bdca4c0-854d-4f73-bca8-cfb78a31f928",
    "jugadores" => "5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc"
))->set(array("estado" => true))->update("torneos_inscripciones");
```

Obviously.. isn't working and I can't find why is the problem exactly, the `estado` field isn't getting updated; probably is more simple than I though but can't get into it. The purpose is to update the `estado` field based on the `jugadores` uuid, in this case `5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc`

---

Based in [B. Fleming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8698101/b-fleming) answer, I made a change to the code:

```php
$this->mongo->where(array(
    "equipo" => "2bdca4c0-854d-4f73-bca8-cfb78a31f928",
    "jugadores.5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc" => array(
        '$exists' => true
)))->set(array("jugadores.5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc" => array("estado" => true)))->update("torneos_inscripciones");
```

The problem now is making the array empty only showing the `estado` field.

Comment: You state that this "isn't working", but can you be more descriptive? Is it just not behaving as expected, or is there an error being thrown? If an error is being throw, then what is the error? The more specific you can be about what problems you're facing, the more easily you can receive an answer that solves your problem.

Comment: What I mean with isn't working is the `estado` field isn't get updated. So I suppose is because the query is mailformed or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having much luck finding any good documentation for the CodeIgniter methods. Their documentation is terrible. From what I can find, however, I suspect that your problem is in your `where` query. Specifically, it looks like you're searching for the value `5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc` for the key `jugadores`. The problem with this lookup is that `5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc` is a field, not a value, so neither MongoDB nor CodeIgniter would know how to handle this lookup.

You might have more success by checking for the existence of the key `5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc`, rather than trying to match it as a value:

```
$this->mongo->where(array(
    "equipo" => "2bdca4c0-854d-4f73-bca8-cfb78a31f928",
    "jugadores.5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc" => array(
        '$exists' => true
    )
))->set(array(
    "jugadores.5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc.estado" => true
))->update("torneos_inscripciones");
```

Please note that I used a single-quoted string, i.e. `'$exists'` instead of `"$exists"`. This is important, because in PHP if you use double-quoted strings, words prefixed with a `$` will be treated as a variable and evaluate the result before inserting into the string. Using single-quoted strings ensures that the value is not interpreted as a variable.

Comment: I've updated the post.. seems like with some changes you made it.. the problem now is when updates the array, is just putting the `estado` inside, instead update it.

Comment: You're fundamentally misunderstanding the way that MongoDB performs updates. Your query itself is designed such that it will overwrite the entire value of `jugadores.5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc` with `array('estado'=>true)`. If you want to update only the single field, then add that field to the field path for your update: `->set(array("jugadores.5361aa85-df9c-4099-8157-fd4d558622cc.estado"=>true))`.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction! Didn't know that you need to literally make the 'path' to the field.